# ListView Example using LinQ and Modal Window

Tags: listview

Can anyone redirect me to a good ListView example in ASP.net using LinQ, VB.net and Modal Window.

What I am trying is list all the records from my Contacts table and when user clicks on any record or tries to add a new record it should open in a modal window and should be able to edit or add a record.

I have seen in many websites when a record is clicked only we will be able to work on the modal popup and the listview refreshes upon closing the window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [article](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/modalpopupextender_example_for.html).  It shows how to use the ModelPopup control from the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit in conjunction with a GridView for editing rows.  It should be easy enough to adapt the sample to use the ListView control instead.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not a big fan of Telerik, they do have [something](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/popupeditform/defaultcs.aspx) like what you want